# PreferenceActivity and empty ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, live-wallpaper

In my PreferenceActivity activity I'm setting ImageView new Bitmap that was returned in onActivityResult method from my Gallery. But when I rotate my phone(Samsung Galaxy Note 2) ImageView becomes empty. How to correctly reinitialize ImageView in this case ?

P.S.

onResume() method doesn't works for this case.

To be more concrete, I have created a topic with an example of my code, here [android image crop and wallpaper settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487371/android-image-crop-and-wallpaper-settings-page)

Could you please tell me what can be wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate, your activity gets destroyed and recreated.  This means all your views are destroyed and all variables are cleared.  There's two ways to fix this:

1)In your manifest, add android:configChanges="orientation" to your activity.  This tells android that you don't want this destroy behvaior for the activity when you rotate.  This will probably be enough to fix it on its own.

2)YOu need to save the filename of the image in a variable.  Then you need to implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save that data.  Then you need to reset the image to use that file when you restore the variable.

I suggest method one- its just easier.

Comment: thanks for your answer !  I already have in my manifest following code and it doesn't work         <activity
            android:name=".WallpaperSettings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>

Comment: This is really strange because sometimes in onActivityResult it correctly sets the picture to ImageView but sometimes ImageView is empty. But Bitmap is always not null

Comment: Sounds like you have a bigger problem and need to post code then.

Comment: Yeah.. I have explained it here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487371/android-image-crop-and-wallpaper-settings-page